# Notification throws RemoteServiceException on Motorola's device with Android 7

Tags: android, push-notification, motorola

After the app received the notification and then build and post a device notification, the notification works fine on all other devices but
not with Motorola's devices like Moo Z Droid, DROID Turbo2, Moto G(4) Plus, Moto G(5) Plus etc. and only with OS > 7.

Did anyone notice the same issue with Motorola devices os > 7?

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package pkg=com.app.packagename: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.app.packagename ……)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6154)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: have you got any solution for this I m also facing the same issues, thanks

Comment: @Amjad Khan, sorry no.

Comment: It is crashing in nougat 7.0 Only

Comment: same issue https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/263